# Can you suggest any world map controls for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, flash, controls

I have a requirement on a website to display an interactive map of the world.

It has to work a bit like the following map

http://www.pentasia.com/flash-map.asp

but I want to be able to hover over each individual country, highlight it as i hover, and then select it. Once selected I want to have a separate display showing information from that country.

Have you seen anything that might fit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik have a good silverlight map control that does it. Here are a couple of their demos:

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/weatherstation/

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Map/Shapefile/Europe

I haven't specifically used their map control so I can't vouch for it personally, but I have used plenty of their other controls with great success and their support is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

you can using ASP.NET ImageMap Control for your requirement.

example described here : http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/ImageMap-Control.aspx